# How to apply realtime template switching in blog website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have a blog app which I develop using [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with  [Flask-Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for retrieve data from database.

I want to implement a realtime template switching client side app for the webpage.

So user able to read the blog post their favourable format.

Planning to implement at least 10 types of predefined format, which user able to select and it will switch the format at realtime.

My question is which is the best javascript library for implement this kind of functionality?

Is Angular JS is good option for it?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS can definitely do this through its routing engine. Whether it is the best way to implement this? It is a perfectly fine choice, and if there isn't another major framework you are familiar with then I would go the Angular route.